# No provider for ControlContainer - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components, angular-forms

I am converting a purchased, third-party template into an Angular 5 app, and just ran into an error. I am very new to Angular 5 (I know AngularJS well however) and don't understand what it's trying to tell me? It seems to be related to a button which shows/hides the top navbar.

**Error Message (from browser):**

```
Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("imalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " (click)="toggleNavigation()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
      [ERROR ->]<form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="form-gro"): ng:///AppModule/TopNavigationNavbarComponent.html@4:6
```

**component.html:**

```
<div class="row border-bottom">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " (click)="toggleNavigation()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
      <form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for something..." class="form-control" name="top-search" id="top-search">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { smoothlyMenu } from '../../../app.helpers';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-navigation-navbar',
  templateUrl: './top-navigation-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-navigation-navbar.component.less']
})
export class TopNavigationNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  toggleNavigation(): void {
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('mini-navbar');
    smoothlyMenu();
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts** (this seems to be something a mentioned a lot when I google this, however it is not the Form throwing the error.)

```
...
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
```

Answer (score 86):

import `FormsModule` in addition to `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: This is not making a difference for me. Still getting the error

Comment: You may have to restart the server for this to work.

Comment: `import FormsModule in addition to ReactiveFormsModule` - this solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 28):

Import `FormsModule` and ReactiveFormsModule in `views.module.ts`(custome module file) file works for me :

**views.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
   ...
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class ViewsModule { }
```

Comment: Works! You have to restart the server for it to take effect.

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure why the error seems to be pointing to the anchor tag outside of the form element, but it was the form element that was causing the error. Adding FormGroup to the form fixed the problem.

```
<form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" [formGroup]="form">
```

Comment: I faced same issue. I have 2 forms in two separate components. I converted only 1 in Angular and got this error. I have to convert both the forms to Angular style to make the app work again

Comment: Omfg, this is it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

Edit the file "app.module.ts"; change the following instruction:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

with the following:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Change the following piece of code:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

with the following:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to display plain HTML form from an Angular component, use `ngNoForm` in `<form>` tag like this.

```
<form ngNoForm>
...
</form>
```

This should prevent Angular from throwing Control Container Error.

Answer (score 3):

After spending 2 hours on it, i realised that when we import FormModule in app.module as well as in child.module then this kind of error occur. Simpley remove FormModule from child.module then error will be resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your component.spec.ts:

```js
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
  RouterTestingModule,
  FormsModule
],
```

Comment: Why component.spec.ts?

Comment: @pzaenger when the problem is in a test

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Angular(Jasmin) Test cases.

I have accidentally added angular form modules in the import of my Unit Test at beforeEach, one is FormModule (by angular) and other one is Custom FormModule.

I need only Custom FormModule, once I removed the FormModule (by angular) the issue resolved

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [CustomTranslateModule.forRoot(),
    CustomRightPanelModule,
    CustomListModule,
    CustomInputTextModule,
    CustomMasterPageModule,
    CustomFormModule,
    FormModule, // this is unnecessary 
    .....................
    .....................
```