# Getting this error "Cannot import "import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms'" after adding angular Reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, formgroups

I want to build a Reactive Form for a simple signup component in Angular. I am trying to
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms' but getting this error. Though I imported {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} in app.module

Error :

```
**core.js:6272 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:5906)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:21251)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatusGroup_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:1073)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:6037)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:12965)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:12181)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:21434)
    at SignupComponent_Template (signup.component.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12141)
    at renderView (core.js:11911)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6272
handleError @ core.js:6325
(anonymous) @ core.js:43091
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:123
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:41772
(anonymous) @ core.js:43088
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
onInvoke @ core.js:41938
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:363
run @ zone-evergreen.js:123
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:857
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41916
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:569
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:552
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:388
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:210
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:230
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:847
then @ zone-evergreen.js:979
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42948
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:44
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:31
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
main.ts:12 Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:5906)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:21251)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatusGroup_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:1073)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:6037)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:12965)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:12181)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:21434)
    at SignupComponent_Template (signup.component.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12141)
    at renderView (core.js:11911)**
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: maybe this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212949/no-provider-for-controlcontainer-angular-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown if you're using the ReactiveFormsModule and an `<form>` element without a FormGroup ie you need to use a form after binding like, [formGroup]="myForm".