# Angular V11: NullInjectorError: No provider for ControlContainer

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom input made in accordance to this article: [medium.com: dont-reinvent-the-wheel](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-a0ed4ad0fafd).

Here is my code, it is in strict mode ▼

```js
// input.component.ts

import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ControlContainer,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    FormControl,
    FormControlDirective,
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
    FloatLabelType,
    MatFormFieldAppearance
} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: InputComponent,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    isDisabled!: boolean;

    @Input() isRequired!: boolean;

    @Input() label!: string;

    @Input() placeholder!: string;

    @Input() readonly!: boolean;

    @Input() appearance: MatFormFieldAppearance = 'fill';

    @Input() floatLabel: FloatLabelType = 'auto';

    @ViewChild(FormControlDirective, { static: true })
    formControlDirective!: FormControlDirective;

    @Input() formControl!: FormControl;

    @Input() formControlName!: string;

    get control(): FormControl {
        return (
            this.formControl ||
            this.controlContainer.control?.get(this.formControlName)
        );
    }

    constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

    clearInput(): void {
        this.control.setValue('');
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor?.registerOnTouched(fn);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor?.registerOnChange(fn);
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor?.writeValue(obj);
    }

    setDisabledState(disabled: boolean): void {
        this.isDisabled = disabled;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- input.component.html -->

<div class="custom-input">
    <mat-form-field
        [appearance]="appearance"
        [floatLabel]="floatLabel"
        class="custom-input__form-field"
    >
        <mat-label class="custom-input__label"
            >{{ label }} <span *ngIf="isRequired && label">*</span></mat-label
        >
        <input
            class="custom-input__value"
            matInput
            type="text"
            [formControl]="$any(control)"
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
            [readonly]="readonly"
        />
        <button
            class="custom-input__clear-btn"
            matSuffix
            mat-icon-button
            aria-label="Clear"
            *ngIf="$any(control).value && !readonly"
            (click)="clearInput()"
        >
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

There is no compiler error but the browser log this error ▼

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ClientsListModule)[ControlContainer -> 
ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> ControlContainer]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ControlContainer!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ClientsListModule)[ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> 
ControlContainer -> ControlContainer -> ControlContainer]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ControlContainer!
```

I've checked similar questions here [Angular 5: "No provider for ControlContainer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959037/angular-5-no-provider-for-controlcontainer) and here [No provider for ControlContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939814/no-provider-for-controlcontainer-and-no-provider-for-controlcontainer) and according to them issue is in not importing both **ReactiveFormsModule** and **FormsModule** in respective module, but I am importing them and still I see that error.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
In components `<app-input>` is used in the following way ▼

[image]

Comment: I think its because you're not setting a `[formGroup]="myForm"` in your html. Can you share where you're trying to use `<app-input>`?

Comment: Try import them in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: @Stoobish I set `[formGroup]="myForm"` in components where it is used.

Comment: @N.F. I tried no change, same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seems you use `formControl` without `formGroup` in some cases, so use `@Optional` decorator to have `controlContainer` null in those cases.

```
constructor(@Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}
```